# Why am I getting GET http://localhost:5000/posts net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I have a React app with a Node backend. I am uploading images/videos on the frontend and saving it as base64. It works fine locally but when I deployed to Vercel there was a 413 error due to the size of the response. I am trying to send the response in chunks to maybe get around this issue.

Backend:

```
export const getPosts = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const maxChunkSize = 500 * 1024; // Maximum chunk size in bytes (e.g., 500KB)
        const posts = await PostMessage.find();

        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json'); // Set the response content type as JSON

        for (const post of posts) {
            const { selectedFile, ...postWithoutFile } = post;

            if (selectedFile) {
                const totalChunks = Math.ceil(selectedFile.length / maxChunkSize);

                for (let i = 0; i < totalChunks; i++) {
                    const start = i * maxChunkSize;
                    const end = (i + 1) * maxChunkSize;
                    const chunk = selectedFile.slice(start, end);

                    res.write(JSON.stringify({ ...postWithoutFile, selectedFile: chunk }));
                    res.write('\n'); // Add a delimiter between posts if needed
                }
            } else {
                res.write(JSON.stringify(post));
                res.write('\n'); // Add a delimiter between posts if needed
            }
        }

        res.end()
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(404).json({ message: error.message });
    }
};
```

Frontend:

```
import axios from 'axios'

const API = axios.create({ baseURL: 'http://localhost:5000' })

API.interceptors.request.use((req) => {
    if (localStorage.getItem('profile')) {
        req.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('profile')).token}`
    }

    return req
})

const fetchPosts = () => API.get('/posts')

export const getPosts = () => async (dispatch) => {
    try {
        const response = await api.fetchPosts();

        console.log('res', response)

        const reader = response.body.getReader();
        let chunks = [];
        let done = false;

        while (!done) {
            const { value, done: isDone } = await reader.read();

            if (value) {
                chunks.push(value);
            }

            done = isDone;
        }

        const completeResponse = new TextDecoder().decode(
            new Uint8Array(chunks.reduce((acc, chunk) => [...acc, ...chunk], []))
        );

        const data = JSON.parse(completeResponse);

        dispatch({ type: 'FETCH_ALL', payload: data });
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error.message);
    }
};
```